# MYSQL allows 0000 year But getting error when retrieving in JAVA

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

HI When we insert the Date in **MYSQL** Server there are certain modes to check invalid dates, such as **NO_ZERO_DATE_MODE** which does not allow **0000-00-00** and **NO_ZERO_IN_DATE** which does not allow **0001-00-00**, but there is no mode which does not allow **0000-01-01**. How can we restrict in MYSQL to allow this type of Dates.

Comment: If you have MySQL version 8+ you could use a check constraint.

Comment: How are you getting it in Java? If your format string uses `y` for the year, changing it to `u` might work.

Comment: @Sweeper i am using just (ResultSet Object)rs.getObject("Date") .

Comment: @Shadow because when i was retrieving with JAVA its throwing invalid Year.

Comment: @juergend it seems ok at DB level to handle this, But i am looking at ,Is MYSQL already have this? instead of managing at our side

Comment: OK, what part of the app do you want to restrict the date? If you want to restrict the date in mysql, then java and mysql connectors are not relevant. If you want to restrict the date in java application code, then mysql and mysql connector tags are not relevant.

Comment: Disable allow_invalid_dates setting? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates

Comment: If this column is not nullable then use `SELECT GREATEST(date_column, 'default date literal'), ..` - this will convert problematic date to valid one. And, as recommended above, use CHECK constraint or triggers and forbid such values storing.

Comment: @Shadow "disable" is not correct term for SQL mode - it can be either specified or skipped.

Comment: @Shadow I am using mysql connector as bridge between mysql and java, Here it  was allowing at the insertion time without any error but when it comes to retrieval it was throwing invalid Year, which was inconsistent in behaviour,

Comment: *it was allowing at the insertion time without any error but when it comes to retrieval it was throwing invalid Year, which was inconsistent in behaviour* Java can save the value but cannot retrieve saved value? Maybe the value saved is not DATE value on Java side, maybe you save string value?

Comment: @Akina Now question routed to 0000-01-01 is valid date?  As per JAVA it was not. Because Geograin claendar dont have zero year

Comment: Nowhere in this discussion is the seemingly important point of where these garbage dates are coming from in the first place mentioned ...

Comment: MySQL accepts `0000-01-01` as valid DATE value (moreover, any DATE literal with zero year and valid month/day is treated as valid, I don't know why, and there is no any bug report about this).

Comment: @g00se there are user inputs and he can do anything, Yes as a developer we will validate, but i am looking , is mysql server itself handles that as those are surely invalid instead of dev headaches

Comment: @Akina i am also same line with you. How it was Valid and no one reported this till now

Comment: In practice DATE column accepts any year value starting from zero whereas the Reference Manual claims that valid value starts from year 1001... maybe simply you're the first man who uses such year value? :)

Comment: @Akina quote from mysql manual: "With ALLOW_INVALID_DATES disabled..."

Comment: @user3309305 is ALLOW_INVALID_DATES sql mode enabled on your server?

Comment: @Shadow these are the modes i have enabled in my server
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: Does your connection enable any other sql server modes by any chance?

Comment: 3023-07-03 will never be invalidated. Yet it's invalid isn't it?

Comment: Ensure you don't insert `true` to database, that is basically `1` second - leading to `0000-01-01`

Comment: @Shadow SQL Server mode is CSV multivalued string. You may either include needed setting into it, in this case this mode is enabled. Or you may not include - in this case the mode is disabled. I.e. you may remove the setting from the list but cannot disable the mode without such removing. This is why the term "disable" seems to be not correcrt.

Comment: @Akina please argue with mysql documentation writers.

Comment: @Shadow I cannot - all RF accounts are disabled by Oracle, so I cannot post a bug (I have more than 10 non-posted bugs now) :(

Comment: @juergend i am trying to go with Check Constraint, but the problem is i have lot of tables in production and there are dynamic columns also to be created, So i am looking for MYSQL Mode but unfortunately i didn't figure it out.

Comment: What date would you have `0000-01-01` be in java?

Comment: @Bohemian we have 0000-01-01 in mysql  Date column, and we not able to retrive it using resultset.getObject

Comment: I ask again: If you *could* retrieve it, what would it be retrieved as?

Comment: @Bohemian here my intention as how can we stop to delete such Dates are going into MYSQL Server,  we have couple of ways to handle this once it went to DB, BY handling exception, by using rs.getString and then format accordingly as your needs